# My textarea sends empty values with ajax for my PHP codes

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

i have created a textarea & i wanna send the values of my textarea with ajax to the database, but it sends it to database without any value and with reloading, where is my problem ? 
html codes :

```
<form>

    <textarea></textarea>   

    <button type="submit">ارسال</button>

</form>
```

ajax codes :

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    var text=$('textarea').val();

    $('button').click(function(e){

        $('.loading').css('display','block');

        $.ajax({

            url:'insertText.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{'text':text},
            beforeSend : function(){

                $('.loading').html('فرستادن ...');

            },
            error : function(request) {

                alert(request);

            },          
            success:function(data){

                alert(data);

            }

        });

    });

});
```

and this is my pdo and mvc for informations , i put last layer :

```
$obj=new Get;
$obj->InsertText($_POST['text']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the line `var text=$('textarea').val();` inside click event of the button, Otherwise it will take only the initial value at the time of dom ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('button').click(function(e) {
        var text = $('textarea').val();
        $('.loading').css('display', 'block');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'insertText.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'text': text
            },
            beforeSend: function() {

                $('.loading').html('فرستادن ...');

            },
            error: function(request) {
                alert(request);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);

            }

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. You are getting the value from the textarea at the wrong time
2. You are submitting the form

---

Your line of code:

```
var text=$('textarea').val();
```

Is inside the `ready` handler but **outside** the `click` hander. This means you get the value at the *time the DOM becomes ready* and not at the time the button is clicked.

Move it inside the click handler.

---

To stop the form submitting, you need to tell the browser not to perform the default action for clicking a submit button:

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

---

Note that, in general, it is better to react for the form being submitted rather than a specific submit button being clicked:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

It is also preferred that the form should still work when the JavaScript fails (for whatever reason):

```
<form action="insertText.php" method="POST">
```

and

```
<textarea name="text">
```